# How would I do the same thing with less code?

Tags: javascript

I am making a unit converter - but my code looks very messy and I am a beginner so I don't know any way to make it more efficient. How would I do make the below code do the same thing but with more logic and less code?

```
let x = document.getElementById("unitAmount");
function convert() {
    const fromUnit = document.getElementById('fromUnitSelector').value;
    const toUnit = document.getElementById('toUnitSelector').value;
    const output = document.getElementById('outputBox');
    
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = x; }
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = (x * 10.7639).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = (x / 508.74).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = (x / 31.79).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = (x / 16.9).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = (x / 1.985).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = (x / 21.39).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = x; }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = (x / 5476).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = (x / 342.25).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = (x / 85.56).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = (x / 21.39).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = (x * 508.74).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = (x * 5476).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = x; }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = (x * 16).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = (x * 64).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = (x * 256).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = (x * 31.79).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = (x * 342.25).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = (x / 16).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = x; }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = (x * 4).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = (x * 16).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = (x * 7.94).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = (x * 85.56).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = (x / 64).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = (x / 4).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = x; }
    if(fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = (x * 4).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 1) { output.value = (x * 1.985).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 2) { output.value = (x * 21.39).toFixed(2); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 3) { output.value = (x / 256).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 4) { output.value = (x / 16).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 5) { output.value = (x / 4).toFixed(4); }
    if(fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 6) { output.value = x; }
}
```

Comment: Try to create data structure with only important values.
Than write proper code to handle it.

Comment: @gkucmierz How would I do that? Can you just provide an example with one of the conversions?

Comment: if we knew where the divisors came from and possibly what determines what does 2 or 4 decimal places, that would help immensely.  It could conceivably be boiled down to a few lines in that case.  But a simple cleanup would be if fromunit = tounit output value = x and then put the rest in an else statement.

Comment: If your `fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 2` conversion rate is `x * 10.7639` then why `fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 1` conversion rate **is not** `x / 10.7639` but it is `x / 21.39`?

Comment: In preparing my answer I noticed a symmetry in the conversion that helped me reduce the code by a lot, but I also noticed a couple of inconsistencies in there that I'm wondering if they're intentional or an error. @Karan points out one example, and there are a couple of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a multi-dimensional array that removes much of the redundancy:

```
function convert() {
    let x = document.getElementById("unitAmount").value;
    const fromUnit = document.getElementById('fromUnitSelector').value;
    const toUnit = document.getElementById('toUnitSelector').value;
    const output = document.getElementById('outputBox'); 

    a = [
        // Each element consists of a value, optionally followed by a toFixed value:
        [
            [ x ], // toUnit == 1
            [ (x * 10.7639), 2 ],    // fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 2
            [ (x / 508.74), 4 ],     // fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 3
            [ (x / 31.79), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 4
            [ (x / 16.9), 4 ],       // fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 5
            [ (x / 1.985), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 1 && toUnit == 6
        ],

        [
            [ (x / 21.39), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 1
            [ x ],                   // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 2
            [ (x / 5476), 4 ],       // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 3
            [ (x / 342.25), 4 ],     // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 4
            [ (x / 85.56), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 5
            [ (x / 21.39), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 2 && toUnit == 6
        ],

        [
            [ (x * 508.74), 2 ],  // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 1
            [ (x * 5476), 2 ],    // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 2
            [ x ],                // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 3
            [ (x * 16), 2 ],      // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 4
            [ (x * 64), 2 ],      // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 5
            [ (x * 256), 2 ],     // fromUnit == 3 && toUnit == 6
        ],

        [
            [ (x * 31.79), 2 ],   // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 1
            [ (x * 342.25), 2 ],  // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 2
            [ (x / 16), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 3
            [ x ],                // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 4
            [ (x * 4), 2 ],       // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 5
            [ (x * 16), 2 ],      // fromUnit == 4 && toUnit == 6
        ],

        [
            [ (x * 7.94), 2 ],    // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 1
            [ (x * 85.56), 2 ],   // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 2
            [ (x / 64), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 3
            [ (x / 4), 4 ],       // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 4
            [ x ],                // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 5
            [ (x * 4), 2 ],       // fromUnit == 5 && toUnit == 6
        ],

        [
            [ (x * 1.985), 2 ],   // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 1
            [ (x * 21.39), 2 ],   // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 2
            [ (x / 256), 4 ],     // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 3
            [ (x / 16), 4 ],      // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 4
            [ (x / 4), 4 ],       // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 5
            [ x ],                // fromUnit == 6 && toUnit == 6
        ],
    ]

    let elmt = a[ fromUnit - 1 ][ toUnit - 1 ];
    let val = elmt[ 0 ]; // Get the value
    if ( elmt[ 1 ] ) { // If it should be toFixed():
        val = val.toFixed( elmt[ 1 ] );
    }
    output.value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at patterns in the conversion, I believe you could **massively** shorten the code by using a lookup map like below.

It works like this:

- If `fromUnit === toUnit` just return x.
- For all cases where `fromUnit < toUnit` you look up `conversionMap[fromUnit][toUnit]`. And the result is a two element array with the conversion factor and either a 1 for multiply or a -1 for divide.
- For all cases where `toUnit < fromUnit` you look up `conversionMap[toUnit][fromUnit]`, using the same conversion factor, but the opposite operation, i.e. 1 for divide, -1 for multiply.
- Your pattern indicates to use `.toFixed(4)` when dividing and `.toFixed(2)` when multiplying, so there's no need to store that additional information.

Here's a CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit currying-frost-udp0c]

```
const conversionMap = {
  1: {
    2: [10.7639, 1],
    3: [508.74, -1],
    4: [31.79, -1],
    5: [16.9, -1],
    6: [1.985, -1],
  },
  2: {
    3: [5476, -1],
    4: [342.25, -1],
    5: [85.56, -1],
    6: [21.39, -1],
  },
  3: {
    4: [16, 1],
    5: [64, 1],
    6: [256, 1],
  },
  4: {
    5: [4, 1],
    6: [16, 1],
  },
  5: {
    6: [4, 1],
  },
};

function handleConversion(x, from, to) {
  if (from === to) return x;
  if (from < to) {
    const [factor, power] = conversionMap[from][to];
    x *= Math.pow(factor, power);
    if (power === 1) return x.toFixed(2);
    return x.toFixed(4);
  } else {
    const [factor, power] = conversionMap[to][from];
    x *= Math.pow(factor, power * -1);
    if (power === 1) return x.toFixed(4);
    return x.toFixed(2);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("input").on("change", changeHandler);
  $("select").on("change", changeHandler);

  function changeHandler() {
    const unitAmount = $("#unitAmount").val();
    const fromUnit = $("#fromUnitSelector").val();
    const toUnit = $("#toUnitSelector").val();

    // using the original convert function
    $("#outputBox1").text(convert(unitAmount, fromUnit, toUnit));
    // using the shorter version
    $("#outputBox2").text(handleConversion(unitAmount, fromUnit, toUnit));
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice one but a suggestion if you like. Why use `3: [508.74, -1]`, Instead use `3: 1/508.74`. When `fromUnit <= toUnit` use `x * conversionMap[fromUnit][toUnit]` else `x / conversionMap[fromUnit][toUnit]`. `adding -1` would require little extra code.

Comment: Because the table OP uses is not 100% consistent with that pattern, sometimes when `from < to` it is multiply and sometimes it is divide, so that bit of info is necessary. Though as you noticed there are some other discrepancies in the conversion factors, so if the OP table is in error and the symmetry holds then your suggestion would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simplify your code without sacrificing much of what little readability it has.

---

**UPDATE:** I seem to have been proven wrong by other answers.

---

But that didn't stop me from trying to use a pairing function to map each `[from, to]` pair to a single key in a map of conversion functions.

You can compare the results of your original function with mine below, to confirm they produce the same output for the same input.

```js
const cantor = (n, y) => ((n + y) * (n + y + 1)) / 2 + y;

const convert = (x, from, to) => ({
  '4': n => n,
  '8': n => (n * 10.7639).toFixed(2),
  '13': n => (n / 508.74).toFixed(4),
  '19': n => (n / 31.79).toFixed(4),
  '26': n => (n / 16.9).toFixed(4),
  '34': n => (n / 1.985).toFixed(4),
  '7': n => (n / 21.39).toFixed(4),
  '12': n => n,
  '18': n => (n / 5476).toFixed(4),
  '25': n => (n / 342.25).toFixed(4),
  '33': n => (n / 85.56).toFixed(4),
  '42': n => (n / 21.39).toFixed(4),
  '11': n => (n * 508.74).toFixed(2),
  '17': n => (n * 5476).toFixed(2),
  '24': n => n,
  '32': n => (n * 16).toFixed(2),
  '41': n => (n * 64).toFixed(2),
  '51': n => (n * 256).toFixed(2),
  '16': n => (n * 31.79).toFixed(2),
  '23': n => (n * 342.25).toFixed(2),
  '31': n => (n / 16).toFixed(4),
  '40': n => n,
  '50': n => (n * 4).toFixed(2),
  '61': n => (n * 16).toFixed(2),
  '22': n => (n * 7.94).toFixed(2),
  '30': n => (n * 85.56).toFixed(2),
  '39': n => (n / 64).toFixed(4),
  '49': n => (n / 4).toFixed(4),
  '60': n => n,
  '72': n => (n * 4).toFixed(2),
  '29': n => (n * 1.985).toFixed(2),
  '38': n => (n * 21.39).toFixed(2),
  '48': n => (n / 256).toFixed(4),
  '59': n => (n / 16).toFixed(4),
  '71': n => (n / 4).toFixed(4),
  '84': n => n
}[cantor(from, to)](x));

for (let from = 1; from <= 6; from++) {
  for (let to = 1; to <= 6; to++) {
    console.log({ n: 1337, from, to, result: convert(1337, from, to) });
  }
}
```

```js
function convert(x, from, to) {
  if (from == 1 && to == 1) { return x; }
  if (from == 1 && to == 2) { return (x * 10.7639).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 1 && to == 3) { return (x / 508.74).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 1 && to == 4) { return (x / 31.79).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 1 && to == 5) { return (x / 16.9).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 1 && to == 6) { return (x / 1.985).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 2 && to == 1) { return (x / 21.39).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 2 && to == 2) { return x; }
  if (from == 2 && to == 3) { return (x / 5476).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 2 && to == 4) { return (x / 342.25).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 2 && to == 5) { return (x / 85.56).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 2 && to == 6) { return (x / 21.39).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 3 && to == 1) { return (x * 508.74).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 3 && to == 2) { return (x * 5476).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 3 && to == 3) { return x; }
  if (from == 3 && to == 4) { return (x * 16).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 3 && to == 5) { return (x * 64).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 3 && to == 6) { return (x * 256).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 4 && to == 1) { return (x * 31.79).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 4 && to == 2) { return (x * 342.25).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 4 && to == 3) { return (x / 16).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 4 && to == 4) { return x; }
  if (from == 4 && to == 5) { return (x * 4).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 4 && to == 6) { return (x * 16).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 5 && to == 1) { return (x * 7.94).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 5 && to == 2) { return (x * 85.56).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 5 && to == 3) { return (x / 64).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 5 && to == 4) { return (x / 4).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 5 && to == 5) { return x; }
  if (from == 5 && to == 6) { return (x * 4).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 1) { return (x * 1.985).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 2) { return (x * 21.39).toFixed(2); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 3) { return (x / 256).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 4) { return (x / 16).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 5) { return (x / 4).toFixed(4); }
  if (from == 6 && to == 6) { return x; }
}

for (let from = 1; from <= 6; from++) {
  for (let to = 1; to <= 6; to++) {
    console.log({ n: 1337, from, to, result: convert(1337, from, to) });
  }
}
```